# excluding files in a fileset not working

Tags: java, ant

I am making a war of a project but i want that classes within that war be picked from specified location and also a jar file A.jar to be picked from custom location i am doing something like this ....

```
<target name="war" depends="a-jar">
    <war destfile="D:/JBOSSHOME/project.war" webxml="${project-location}/web/WEB-INF/web.xml">
        <fileset dir="${project-location}/web" >
        <exclude name="${project-location}/web/WEB-INF/lib/A.jar"/>
        <exclude name="${project-location}/web/WEB-INF/classes/**/*.class"/> 
        </fileset>
        <lib dir="${jarsLocation}"></lib>
        <classes dir="D:/JBOSSHOME/project/build/classes"/>
    </war>
</target>
```

but in the resultant war i am getting 2 A.jar files and also classes are getting copied from ${project-location}/web/WEB-INF/classes instead of the classes dir that i have provided...
Any help would be much appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exclude shouldn't include the root directory of your file set:

```
<fileset dir="${project-location}/web" >
    <exclude name="WEB-INF/lib/A.jar"/>
    <exclude name="WEB-INF/classes/**/*.class"/> 
</fileset>
```